# script auto copying itself to startup for ease of use. permission denied, even when run with administrator

Tags: vbscript

I'm currently making a script that runs on startup, and if it's not already doing that, it installs into C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup using FileSystemObject (shortened to FSO in the code) .CopyFile ScriptFullName to SpecialFolders ("Startup") but it returns an error

Line: 12
Char: 1
Error: Permission denied
Code: 800A0046
Source: Microsoft VBScript runtime error

This is for an application to easily installing any VBScript into Startup (no clue what it's gonna be now)

```
set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
If WScript.Arguments.Length = 0 Then
  Set ObjShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
  ObjShell.ShellExecute "wscript.exe" _
    , """" & WScript.ScriptFullName & """ RunAsAdministrator", , "runas", 1
  WScript.Quit
End if
  strStartup = WshShell.SpecialFolders ("Startup")
  strCurrent = WScript.ScriptFullName
Dim FSO
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
FSO.CopyFile strCurrent, strStartup

x=msgbox("lol", 0, "lol")
```

I want to have it run as admin (it does) and not return the error Permission denied

Comment: Shouldnt CopyFile target also be a file not a folder?

Comment: oh my god thank you! This has worked perfectly! @u@

Answer (score 0):

Stephen Quan has answered the question - 
CopyFile needs to target a file, not a folder!